# How do I create a #define mapping to the spacebar character in C?

Tags: c, macros, space

I'm looking for the equivalent of this, without the surrounding single quotes:

```
#define SPACEBAR ' '
```

How do I do this? For any other character I would use either the character itself or its corresponding escape character. To my knowledge, however, there's no escape character for the spacebar. Is there some sort of hex code I can use? Please help.

Comment: May I ask for a purpose of such a definition? How would it be used?

Comment: It is probably impossible. What is the use case? Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Mostly curiosity to be honest.

Comment: So for the `%` character, you'd use `#define PERCENT %`? How would you use that? It's not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish that's not done better and more clearly by `#define SPACEBAR ' '` -- or just using a literal `' '` when you need that value. (BTW, the character is called SPACE; the "spacebar" is the thing on your keyboard that you press to produce a space character.)

Comment: I was just wondering if it was possible. Why the hostility? Is this the wrong forum to be asking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some sort of hex code I can use?

The ASCII code for Space is `32` or `0x20`. If you want to use `SPACEBAR` like a constant, you can `#define` it to be:

```
#define SPACEBAR 32
```

or

```
#define SPACEBAR 0x20
```

**Caveat**

The above encoding will work for systems that use ASCII and UTF-8 encoding. For systems that use EBCDIC encoding, the decimal value to encode Space is 64 (Thanks are due to @BasileStarynkevitch for pointing that out).

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: That defines `SPACEBAR` to be equivalent of the space character in C. Isn't that the question?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, what's your understanding of the question?

Comment: If this is the answer of the question, it might be `#define SPACEBAR  ((char)32)`  and this depends upon an encoding (e.g. ASCII, UTF-8, but not EBCDIC) compatible with that value.

Comment: Writing `#define SPACEBAR 32` or `#define SPACEBAR 0x20` is equivalent to `#define SPACEBAR ' '` (assuming an ASCII-based character set). The latter is more portable and much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SPACEBAR 32
```

OR

```
char ch = 0x20
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Depending of what you exactly want to do, you may be able to use:

```
#define SPACEBAR \040
```

It is the octal value of the space char, like it may appear in a string.

Comment: I can't think of any way you could use that macro in valid C code.